# How to tell PhPpstorm a returned variable is an instance of something?

Tags: php, oop, instance, phpstorm

Normally if I do something like this: `$user = new User();`
I can then do `$user->...` and PhPstorm suggests the available methods (e.g. getName() or getEmail())

But when I call a function that returns an instance of a class from inside another function, then this doesn't work anymore.

Like this:

```
public function foo() {
    $userService = // ;
    $user = $userService->createUser();

    $user->getName()
}

class UserService {
    public function createUser(){
        $user = new User();
        return $user;
    }
}
```

the $user->getName() inside foo() now shows up as an undefined method, because it doesn't know it's an instance of User. It still works fine though and I get the expected name, but my PhPstorm is somehow not smart enough to know this is a User object. How do I tell PhPstorm this.

Comment: Try [http://superuser.com/](http://superuser.com/). This is off-topic for SO

Comment: Try adding /** @return NameOfTheUserClass **/ as comment for the function

Comment: Pretty sure programming tools are on-topic for SO.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the type of the variable with an annotation above the variable instanciation :

```
/** @var YourNamespace\YourClassName $user */
$user = new User();
```

Or in the docblock of the function

```
/**
* Description of the function
* @return YourNamespace\YourClassName
*/
function myFunction()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: the first option works, but it is quite ugly. The second one does not however, which is odd. I tried putting the @var in the docblock aswell, but that made it stop working. So I hope there is another solution.

Comment: @Boneshock Everything works. You must be missing something or doing it wrong (e.g. missing leading `\ ` for namespace). Show you code with those PHPDoc comments.

Comment: when using naked new()s phpstorm normally doesn't need the code block. not sure why op finds it ugly, I find it pretty cool